# wp_list_categories with show_count, except for specific categories

Tags: categories

I want to show post count for all child categories shown, but not for their parent categories. Or, since there are only 3 parent categories, this exclusion could be per category id.

Is there a way to do that?

Also, unfortunately, the number doesn't come wrapped in any element, so I can't think of any way of hiding it CSS wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17324/wrap-post-count-in-a-span) post. It shows you how you can wrap the count with any element you'd like so that you can manipulate it as you see fit.