# How do I add <span> after the <a> tag in WordPress widget?

Tags: widgets

Here's my code:

```
<li class="genre"><a href="#">History</a>(86)</li>
```

I want the output like this:

```
<li class="genre"><a href="#">History</a><span>(86)</span></li>
```

Comment: Is it your widget or a widget from a plugin?

Comment: It's a plugin, https://wordpress.org/plugins/list-custom-taxonomy-widget/ @SörenWrede

Comment: That plugin uses `wp_list_categories()` under the hood, so this answer will work: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/17326/39152